# Update column value with value from another row where specific column is the same

Tags: sql, sql-update, firebird

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE STOTMARS
(
  KODAS integer NOT NULL,
  PUNKTAS varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  MARS varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  EILNR integer NOT NULL,
  METRAI integer NOT NULL,
  VIDGR integer NOT NULL,
  TARPINIS varchar(1),
  CONSTRAINT STOTMARS_ID PRIMARY KEY (KODAS,PUNKTAS,MARS,EILNR)
);
CREATE INDEX STOTMARS_EILNR ON STOTMARS (EILNR);
CREATE INDEX STOTMARS_KODAS ON STOTMARS (KODAS);
CREATE INDEX STOTMARS_MARS ON STOTMARS (MARS);
CREATE INDEX STOTMARS_PUNKTAS ON STOTMARS (PUNKTAS);
GRANT DELETE, INSERT, REFERENCES, SELECT, UPDATE
 ON STOTMARS TO  SYSDBA WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

I need to update value of EILNR in rows where PUNKTAS = 'Dvaro st.3' with EILNR value from row with the same KODAS value and PUNKTAS value of 'Centro st.1'

So far I tried:

```
update STOTMARS a
set a.EILNR = (
    select
        b.EILNR
    from STOTMARS b
    where a.PUNKTAS = 'Centro st.1' and a.MARS = b.MARS
)
where a.PUNKTAS = 'Dvaro st.3'
```

but this gives me error:

```
Executing statement...
Error: *** IBPP::SQLException ***
Context: Statement::Execute( update STOTMARS a
set a.EILNR = (
    select
        b.EILNR
    from STOTMARS b
    where a.PUNKTAS = 'Centro st.1' and a.MARS = b.MARS
)
where a.PUNKTAS = 'Dvaro st.3' )
Message: isc_dsql_execute2 failed

SQL Message : -625
The insert failed because a column definition includes validation constraints.

Engine Code    : 335544347
Engine Message :
validation error for column EILNR, value "*** null ***"


Total execution time: 0.000s
```

To make it more clear query:

```
select
a.MARS, a.EILNR, b.EILNR
from STOTMARS a
join STOTMARS b
on a.MARS = b.MARS and b.PUNKTAS = 'Dvaro st.3'
where a.PUNKTAS = 'Centro st.1'
```

gives me a table where each third column value should be replace with that row's second column value.

Comment: What does "this does not work" mean?  Your first query is the query I would expect.

Comment: it gives me error: select
SQL Message : -625
The insert failed because a column definition includes validation constraints.

Comment: Please post the DDL of your tables and include all relevant information, including errors in your question.

Comment: I reedited entire answer with all actual table info and full error

Comment: Your query does not match your described goal. *with EILNR value from row with the **same KODAS** value and PUNKTAS value of 'Centro st.1'* but then suddenly *update .... from STOTMARS b
    where a.PUNKTAS = 'Centro st.1' **and a.MARS = b.MARS** --* - so what is the exact idea? And it all in general contradicts your Primary Key definition too. You are expected to check ALL the columns in PK to get the UNIQUE value, so checking just PART of PK woul potentially give you MANY rows instead of single one on some data. I think your very data scheme is not well thought through...

Comment: I suggest you to read https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem - I come to think you have to make a step back and review the overall data flow and DB structure, at very least to make explicit and clear all the assumptions and expectations and check all the guards to ensure those.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the inner-select yields no rows, and therefor the update tries to assign `null`, because the conditions applied are mutually exclusive, and this fails because of a `NOT NULL` constraint on `EILNR`:

```
update STOTMARS a
set a.EILNR = (
    select
        b.EILNR
    from STOTMARS b
    where a.PUNKTAS = 'Centro st.1' and a.MARS = b.MARS
)
where a.PUNKTAS = 'Dvaro st.3'
```

`a.PUNKTAS` can't be `'Centro st.1'` and `'Dvaro st.3'` at the same time. The condition in the inner-select should probably use `b.PUNKTAS`:

```
where b.PUNKTAS = 'Centro st.1' and a.MARS = b.MARS
```

You might also want to consider using [`MERGE`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-dml-merge) instead of this correlated update.

Comment: MERGE is definitely better here. Though it would not solve the underlying problem: he thinks that for every 'Dvaro st.3' row he has a corresponding 'Centro st.1' row, which is not true.

Comment: @Arioch'The We don't know that given the lack of information. However, with `MERGE` you can at least avoid that problem using a `WHEN MATCHED`-clause.

Comment: There is another potential problem - what if the SELECT returns not zero rows but multiple? correlated update would crash instantly. MERGE would do much more sinister thing - it would mask the problem, running many updates of the row in random order. Race conditions. There seems to be something very very wrong about this database. XY problem again, perhaps. I fear answering his literal question we are helping person to harm oneself by delusion.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid `NULL` in several ways.  One way is to replace the value with an appropriate value:

```
update STOTMARS a
    set a.EILNR = (select coalesce(max(b.EILNR), 0)
                   from STOTMARS b
                   where a.PUNKTAS = 'Centro st.1' and a.MARS = b.MARS
                  )
    where a.PUNKTAS = 'Dvaro st.3';
```

Or alternatively, add a comparison clause:

```
update STOTMARS a
    set a.EILNR = (select coalesce(max(b.EILNR), 0)
                   from STOTMARS b
                   where a.PUNKTAS = 'Centro st.1' and a.MARS = b.MARS
                  )
    where a.PUNKTAS = 'Dvaro st.3' and
          (select b.EILNR
           from STOTMARS b
           where a.PUNKTAS = 'Centro st.1' and a.MARS = b.MARS
          ) is not null;
```

Note that this does not use `not exists`, so it can take into account `NULL` value sin `EILNR`.

Comment: the latter statement looks redundant, better be written as MERGE :-D

Comment: You have missed the problem with the contradiction of `a.PUNKTAS = 'Centro st.1'` vs `a.PUNKTAS = 'Dvaro st.3'`